# Are there any good explanations of kernel schedulers?

Tags: linux-kernel, kernel, scheduling

I've recently begun wondering about kernel schedulers and whatnot. Is there any resource that provides an overview of commonly used kernel scheduling algorithm? The CFS scheduler has a lot of literature on its implementation, but I can't seem to find much along the lines of the queuing theory behind the algorithm.

Comment: This should be covered in undergraduate course literature: might be beneficial to visit a local campus library/bookstore and take a peek.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Linux Kernel Scheduler Resources:**

[Inside the Linux scheduler](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/linux/library/l-scheduler/)

[A short history of Linux schedulers](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/linux/library/l-completely-fair-scheduler/index.html)

[Completely Fair Scheduler (since 2.6.23)](http://www.linuxjournal.com/magazine/completely-fair-scheduler?page=0,0)

[Multiprocessing with the Completely Fair Scheduler](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/linux/library/l-cfs/index.html)

[Real-Time Linux Kernel Scheduler](http://www.linuxjournal.com/article/10165)

[O(1) Scheduler (prior 2.6.23)](http://www.linuxjournal.com/article/7178)

[Linux Scheduler simulation](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/linux/library/l-linux-scheduler-simulator/index.html)

Answer (score 0):

This [set of docs](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/views/linux/libraryview.jsp?sort_by=&show_abstract=true&show_all=&search_flag=&contentarea_by=Linux&search_by=scheduler&topic_by=-1&industry_by=-1&type_by=All%20Types&ibm-search=Search) have been the most helpful for me by far although they don't talk about the queuing theory behind the algorithms.